# Scrapy yield items as sub-items in JSON

Tags: python, json, scrapy

How can I tell Scrapy to divide all yielded items into two lists? For instance, let's say I have two main types of items - `article` and `author`. I want to have them in two separate lists. Right now I am getting output JSON:

```
[
  {
    "article_title":"foo",
    "article_published":"1.1.1972",
    "author": "John Doe"
  },
  {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 42,
    "email": "foo@example.com"
  }
]
```

How do I convert it to something like this?

```
{
  "articles": [
    {
      "article_title": "foo",
      "article_published": "1.1.1972",
      "author": "John Doe"
    }
  ],
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "age": 42,
      "email": "foo@example.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

My functions for outputting these are simple, similar to this:

```
def parse_author(self, response):
        name = response.css('div.author-info a::text').extract_first()
        print("Parsing author: {}".format(name))

        yield {
            'author_name': name
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Items will reach the pipeline separately and add each accordingly with this setup:

items.py

```
class Article(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    published = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()

class Author(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    age = scrapy.Field()
```

spider.py

```
def parse(self, response):

    author = items.Author()
    author['name'] = response.css('div.author-info a::text').extract_first()
    print("Parsing author: {}".format(author['name']))
    yield author

    article = items.Article()
    article['title'] = response.css('article css').extract_first()
    print("Parsing article: {}".format(article['title']))

    yield article
```

pipelines.py

```
process_item(self, item, spider):
    if isinstance(item, items.Author):
        # Do something to authors
    elif isinstance(item, items.Article):
        # Do something to articles
```

---

**I suggest though this architecture:**

```
[{
    "title": "foo",
    "published": "1.1.1972",
    "authors": [
        {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "age": 42,
        "email": "foo@example.com"
        },
        {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "age": 21,
        "email": "bar@example.com"
        },
    ]
}]
```

This makes it go all in one item.

items.py

```
class Article(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    published = scrapy.Field()
    authors = scrapy.Field()
```

spider.py

```
def parse(self, response):

    authors = []
    author = {}
    author['name'] = "John Doe"
    author['age'] = 42
    author['email'] = "foo@example.com"
    print("Parsing author: {}".format(author['name']))
    authors.append(author)

    article = items.Article()
    article['title'] = "foo"
    article['published'] = "1.1.1972"
    print("Parsing article: {}".format(article['title']))
    article['authors'] = authors
    yield article
```

Comment: I'm still not sure how to group all items of a given type under one JSON key. Modifying the pipeline to return `{'author': item}` still creates a single `author` key for every item. I guess I need to accumulate all items in my own list somewhere and then at the very end output them as a JSON, but I do not know where to to that. ::: Your suggested architecture is good if I want to primarily iterate through articles. It makes it much harder to list all authors, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
raw = [
    {
        "article_title":"foo",
        "article_published":"1.1.1972",
        "author": "John Doe"
    },
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "age": 42,
        "email": "foo@example.com"
    }
]

data = {'articles':[], "authors":[]}

for a in raw:

    if 'article_title' in a:
        data['articles'].extend([ a ])

    else:
        data['articles'].extend([ a ])
```

Comment: I am not sure how to handle dictionaries like that in Scrapy. `yield`ing from a parsing function passes the dictionary straight to Scrapy and I am not able to process it in the end. Can you expand on your answer please?

Comment: @MartinMelka process means where? sorry I didnt get your question ... what I understand is that your data should be accessible in pipeline by `item['articles']`